# How do I add an SSL certificate to the default Elastic Beanstalk endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to add an SSL cert to my default EB endpoint. I know how to add a certificate for another domain however to save routing EB to a domain (and paying for a domain) can I get an SSL for the default AWS subdomain my EB is hosted on?

If I apply a SSL cert for another domain to the default endpoint the certificate is invalid and this causes all kinds of problems.

Comment: You can't obtain an SSL certificate for a domain you don't own, and you don't own the default Elastic Beanstalk endpoint domain. You will need to point your own domain to your Elastic Beanstalk environment before you can enable SSL.

Comment: Thanks. Good to confirm.